# Using a new type in Python C Extension

Tags: python-2.7, python-c-extension

I have written code to define a new-type in Python C extension (MyStatus).
I wrote the C code to define allocation,deallocation etc as mentioned in this [page](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html).

I was able to compile the module and use it from python.

Now i am trying to use this new type in another Python C extension (TestStatus)
My requirement is i need to have only one .so for this.
I dont want to use MyStatus directly from Python code.
I will be only importing TestStatus in my code and i want to initialize the MyStatus from my C extension written for TestStatus.

I have written code like this for TestStatus

```
static PyObject * TestStatus_checkPyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject * mystatus = NULL;
    const char *command;

    /* Call the class object. */
    mystatus = PyObject_CallObject((PyObject *) &MyStatusType, NULL);

    return mystatus;
}

    PyMODINIT_FUNC initTestStatus(void)
    {
        (void) Py_InitModule("TestStatus", TestMethods);

        initMyStatus();//This is available in the C code written for MyStatus
    }
```

I was able to create the so like what i have mentioned in code.
But i am stuck on setting the variables for MyStatus which is a integer and char*(PyObject*)
Can somebody throw some light on this, like whether my approach is right and how to initialize and use MyStatus from TestStatus with arguments.

> I am trying this with Python 2.6.6 on Rhel 6.3

In MyStatus i have 2 variables

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    int         mStatus;
    PyObject    *mErrorString;
} MyStatus;
```

I need to initialize the same from TestStatus.

Comment: You're stuck on setting "the variables", which variables? can you be more specific, that would help. Why is it required to have only on `.so` file? Would it work, if you put the code of both modules in one file? - Sorry, but I did not quit get the problem, so it's hard to shed some light on it.

Comment: I have edited the post to add information about the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Python C extension should provide a [C-API](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#providing-a-c-api-for-an-extension-module) to be used from other C modules. So in your case sou should have something in your `MyStatus.h`  like

```c
/* Header file for MyStatus module */

#ifndef MyStatus_MODULE_H
#define MyStatus_MODULE_H
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    int         mStatus;
    PyObject    *mErrorString;
} MyStatus;

#define MyStatus_Type_NUM 0

#define MyStatus_New_NUM 1
#define MyStatus_New_RETURN MyStatus *
#define MyStatus_New_PROTO (int mStatus, PyObject *mErrorString)

/* Total number of C API pointers */
#define MyStatus_API_pointers 2

#ifdef MyStatus_MODULE
/* do nothing for this minimal example */
#else

static void **MyStatus_API;

#define MyStatus_Type (*(PyTypeObject *)(\
    MyStatus_API[MyStatus_Type_NUM]))

#define MyStatus_New \
 (*(MyStatus_New_RETURN (*)MyStatus_New_PROTO) \
  MyStatus_API[MyStatus_New_NUM])

static int import_MyStatus(void)
{
    MyStatus_API = (void **)PyCapsule_Import("MyStatus._C_API", 0);
    return (MyStatus_API != NULL) ? 0 : -1;
}
#endif /* !defined(MyStatus_MODULE) */
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif /* !defined(MyStatus_MODULE_H) */
```

and define something like

```c
static Py MyStatus *
PyMyStatus_New(int mStatus, PyObject *mErrorString){
    MyStatus *self;
    self = (MyStatus *)MyStatusType.tp_alloc(&MyStatusType, 0);
    self->mStatus = mStatus;
    Py_INCREF(mErrorString); // in case you don't want to steal a reference
    self->mErrorString = mErrorString;
    if (!self->mErrorString){
        Py_DECREF(self);
        return NULL;
    }
    return self;
}

#ifndef PyMODINIT_FUNC  /* declarations for DLL import/export */
#define PyMODINIT_FUNC void
#endif PyMODINIT_FUNC initMyStatus(void){
    PyObject *m = Py_InitModule3("MyStatus", methods, "");
    static void *MyStatus_API[MyStatus_API_pointers];

    MyStatus_API[MyStatus_Type_NUM] = (void *)&MyStatusType;
    MyStatus_API[MyStatus_New_NUM] = (void *)MyStatus_New;

    PyObject *c_api_object = PyCapsule_New((void *)MyStatus_API, "MyStatus._C_API", NULL);
    if (c_api_object != NULL) PyModule_AddObject(m, "_C_API", c_api_object); }
```

in the `MyStauts.c`. Additionally, it is very convenient to 
define macros like

```
PyMyStatus_SET_MSTATUS(self, mStatus)
PyMyStatus_GET_MSTATUS(self)
PyMyStatus_SET_mErrorString(self, mErrorString)
PyMyStatus_GET_mErrorString(self)
```

to be able to change the underlying structure of MyStatus later on and to handle the reference counts.

If you don't want to do this, you can always initialize and modify `MyStatus` objects directly, like shown in the upper example for the `MyStatus_New` function.

In `TestStatus.c` finally import the C-API.

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC initTestStatus(void){
    import_MyStatus();
    Py_InitModule3("TestStatus", methods, "");

}
```

Now you will be able to use `MyStatus_New` and `MyStatusType`.

Comment: I have this code as part of MyStatus. But my doubt is how should i call this from TestStatus. As you can see i am calling initMyStatus. But in the methods of TestStatus, i should initialize a object of MyStatus initialize it with errorstring and status. Thats where i am stuck

Comment: I see. I think the problem is that you try to call `initMyStatus();` in `initTestStatus`. You need to call `import_MyStatus();` which you have to define in the `MyStatus` module, to import the C-API. Then you are able to call functions from `MyStatus` in `TestStatus` and use the type if you exported it via the C-API.

Comment: Will try this and let u know...Thanks for your input

Comment: Was your try successful?

Comment: I was on vacation...so need to try this week...will update you soon

Comment: I need to use Python 2.6 for this and when i tried to execute this, i was getting linker error that PyCapsule_New is undefined.

Comment: yes for python 2.6, the C-API export is slightly more lengthy (see [docs](http://docs.python.org/2.6/extending/extending.html#providing-a-c-api-for-an-extension-module)) but can be transferred from the example in the docs to your module straightforwardly.

Comment: I have one issue. With the link i am able to compile the module. After doing that i found it needs the MyStatus as a Python module, present in python lib directory. I dont want it in that fashion. What i require is a single module and i may not expose MyStaus outside my module.

Comment: You should be able to put everything in one file, the definition of the `MyStatus` type and the `TestStatus` type. In that case you don't even need to import the C-API explicitly. However, the way you create and interact with MyStatus objects should remain the same, e.g. via `PyMyStatus_New`. What I don't get is, why `MyStatus` should be a python type if you don't want to expose it to python. In that case I would just use normal C structs and functions instead of dealing with a complicated python C-API.

Comment: Let me spend some time on this..and get back

Comment: I need to expose MyStatus also to python. But i dont want the user too import MyStatus as a separate module or create a new.so for that. The return from TestStatus is MyStatus and user should be using MyStatus that way.